# JTable: get object location inside a cell

Tags: java, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I can't figure out how to solve this problem:

I have a JTable with a custom cell renderer. Inside a cell renderer I put a JLabel with a grid bag layout.

If I try to obtain the location of the JLabel inside the renderer, I always get 0, 0. I tried to revalidate the JLabel before but I'm not able to find a correct solution.

This is the code of the custom renderer:

```
public CustomRenderer() {
    // set the renderer layout to null
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    // create the layouts label
    layoutsLbl = new JLabel("Layout");
    // create a grid bag constraints instance
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    // first column
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    // first row
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    // maximum horizontal weight
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    // anchor to the top left corner
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    // fill horizontally
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    // set the insets
    gbc.insets = new Insets(35, 0, 10, 0);
    // add the layouts label to the view
    add(layoutsLbl, gbc);
}

public String clickCheck() {
    // revalidate the layouts label
    layoutsLbl.revalidate();
    // get the layouts label location
    System.out.println("Label location: " + layoutsLbl.getLocation());
}
```

I know that in some cases I might be able to calculate the JLabel location because it is fixed, but I would like to have a general approach because I need it for a renderer where I have a lot of dinamically generated JLabel.

The final goal is to find the location of each JLabel to be able to identify which JLabel has been clicked with a MouseListener attached to the table. I'm able to find the clicked cell, the mouse location in the cell and therefore I need the JLabel location in the cell to test it against the mouse location.

Comment: The problem is that the JLabel in the renderer is used as a rubberstamp to draw the cells. There is only one JLabel for the renderer and thus the column, and it is not being displayed (just used as a rubberstamp). At least that's the general way of working in JTables, see [DefaultTableCellRenderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableCellRenderer.html) implementation note. However we're not seeing a [MCVE] in your question, so if you want concrete help, I suggest you provide one.

Comment: ^+1 for a [MCVE]. Right now, it's not even clear whether you extend `DefaultTableCellRenderer` or created one on your own.

Comment: Sorry You are right. I need to convert a big class to something simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The final goal is to find the location of each JLabel to be able to identify 
>   Blockquote which JLabel has been clicked with a MouseListener attached to the table.

This Problem is pretty easy to solve. Just use this simple Code snippet to get the clicked Object.

```
this.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            Component clicked = getComponentAt(e.getPoint());
            if(clicked instanceof JLabel){
                JLabel myLabel = (JLabel) clicked;
                //obviously myLabel is the clicked JLabel
                System.out.println("Clicked Label: " + myLabel.getLocation());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

        }
    });
```

Using the `getLocation()` Method will now give you the real Location the `JLabel` has.

> UPDATE: Here is the requested complete Example (Using `JTable` instead)

This is my Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame =  new JFrame();
    frame.setContentPane(new CostumTable());
    frame.getContentPane().addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            Component clicked = frame.getContentPane().getComponentAt(e.getPoint());
            if(clicked instanceof JLabel){
                JLabel myLabel = (JLabel) clicked;
                //obviously myLabel is the clicked JLabel
                System.out.println("Text of clicked Label: " + myLabel.getText());
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

        }
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

        }
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

        }
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

        }

    });

    frame.setSize(200, 500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

and this would be the CustomRenderer (now CostumTable):

```
    public CostumTable() {
    // set the renderer layout to GridBagLayout
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    // create the layouts label
    layoutsLbl = new JLabel("Layout");
    // create a grid bag constraints instance
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    // first column
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    // first row
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    // maximum horizontal weight
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    // anchor to the top left corner
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    // fill horizontally
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    // set the insets
    gbc.insets = new Insets(35, 0, 10, 0);
    // add the layouts label to the view
    add(layoutsLbl, gbc);


    //Just here to test the MousListener
    List<JLabel> testLabel = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        testLabel.add(new JLabel("TestLabel number " + i));
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = i + 1;
        add(testLabel.get(i), gbc);
    }
    //
}

public String clickCheck() {
    // revalidate the layouts label
    layoutsLbl.revalidate();
    // get the layouts label location
    System.out.println("Label location: " + layoutsLbl.getLocation());
    return null; //I dont know what you want to return
}
```

Comment: It's not working. Can You please confirm that You are adding the mouse listener to the renderer?

Comment: @GavynSykes Yes I do. What exactly is the problem you're running into?

Comment: if I add a mouse listener to the renderer, nothing happens, also if I try to simply write something to the console. The mouse listener responds if it is attached to the JTable, not to the renderer. Maybe I'm missing something? Could You please provide a full working example? Thanks a lot

Comment: Would adding the `MouseListener` to the `JTable` directly be a problem? As this is most likely the solution with less risk for problems

Comment: But if I add the MouseListener to the JTable, the getComponentAt will always return the JTable itself

Comment: well thats strange I tryed it with 5 Test-JLabels which worked perfectly fine. How did you add the `MouseListener`?

Comment: With the same code You posted. Can You provide your example? Thanks so much

Comment: @GavynSykes I added the requested code, does this work for you?

Comment: thanks @DerBobby your code is working. I just need to find out why it's not working inside my completed application. Thanks again, I really appreciated Your help